# Routers will not cascade

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, dd-wrt

I'm attempting to cascade two routers to extend my wireless network, using a Linksys E1200 as a master and a Linksys E1500 as a slave. The E1200 is running the stock firmware but the E1500 is running DD-WRT.

I have read this: http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/33700-42-ultimate-modem-router-setup-thread and I followed the first option to the letter and failed. I am able to achieve only limited connectivity. I also read this: http://www.wikihow.com/Cascade-Routers and tried both options and failed both times.

Now, I have done a 30/30/30 on the slave router, so it's gone back to the default DD-WRT settings. The master I'd like to leave be if at all possible. Can someone give me a step-by-step guide to cascading these two routers or explain why this setup will not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DHCP must be disabled on the second, or "slave" router as you put it.  DD-WRT settings allow you to disable both easily.

The IP address of the second router must be on the same subnet as the first (i.e. if your first router's LAN IP is 192.168.1.1, make your second router's 192.168.1.254 or something else that doesn't conflict with the first router's DHCP scope).

You then have two options:

- Connect a Ethernet cable from one of the first router's LAN ports to one of the second router's LAN ports.  In DD-WRT, put the router in AP mode and configure your desired AP settings accordingly.  It's up to you whether you use the same SSID as your first router or a different one.  The second router will pull DHCP from the first router, and traffic will go to it.
- If you can't run a cable (running a cable is the best thing speed wise), put DD-WRT on the second router into [Repeater Bridge](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge) mode.  I believe due to the unit in Repeater Bridge mode having to switch constantly between AP and client mode the speed is halved.  Pay attention to this (from [this](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Repeater_Bridge)):

> Note: If you are unsure of what you are doing, is advisable to
>   practice by setting up the router first in client bridge mode and get
>   it working correctly. Client bridge mode is simpler but most of the
>   settings are the same. Once you understand how to set up a client
>   bridge and have it working, then proceed to setting up repeater bridge

Comment: Ah, found my problem. I went and got a different Cat cable and tried that. Worked like a charm. What you said works though, so it's a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using one of the four switch ports on the 2nd router? or are you using the Uplink port?  Using the Uplink port may cause issues.  Just treat it as a switch to switch cascade via cat-5 ethernet.